# Can arthropods rotate their joints?

Tags: anatomy, arthropod

I've been recently researching arthropod exoskeletons, and one thing I've seen more than once is that exoskeletons, due to how they work, only really allow for hinge joints. However, from seeing flies and mantises, I've more than once seen tilting or even rotation of the head. I've tried searching more, but all I found was how mantises are the only arthropods capable of rotating their heads, a process that I couldn't find an explanation for.

Essentially my question is: **can arthropods in general rotate their joints or are mantises truly alone in their ability to have rotation with an exoskeleton as far as we know?** While it's not the main goal of the question, I'd really appreciate an explanation on how exactly mantises achieve this rotation